# Как извлечь из БД даты начиная с самой маленькой, периодичность - месяц

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Необходимо достать из БД даты, начиная с самой "старой", например, 2016-01-01 - это самая старая запись, дальше даты растут ежедневно и по несколько записей в день, а следующую дату мне нужно вытянуть через месяц, т.е 2016-02-01 игнорируя, всё что между. И записать в массив, в PHP, и так далее, до самой новой даты.

Как написать такой SQL запрос?

Comment: *следующую дату мне нужно вытянуть через месяц* Понятие "месяц" - не является определённым (в отличие от, например, 30 дней).  Сохранение номера дня приводит к странным результатам - скажем, добавляя по "месяцу" к 31 августа, через год получишь 28 (или 29) августа. Следует более внимательно отнестись к формулировке задачи.

Comment: 2016-01-01, следующая 2016-02-01. Я думаю я вполне доступно написал.

Comment: А если 2016-08-31, то следующие? хотя бы парочку...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К примеру, это можно попробовать выгрузить подобным селектом:

```
SELECT min(DATE_FORMAT(t.datecolumn,'%Y/%m/%d')) FROM table t
group by DATE_FORMAT(t.datecolumn , '%Y-%m')
```

Группируем записи по месяцам и выбираем минимальное значения для месяца, так же можно выбрать максимальное значение для месяца в таблице заменив `min` на `max`. В выводе не обязательно менять формат даты, т.е. `select min(t.datecoloum)...` тоже сработает

upd:
Если необходимо подставлять минимальный день из самой минимальной даты к каждому месяцу, то запрос будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
SELECT CONCAT(MIN(date_format(t.datecolumn,'%Y.%m.')),(SELECT MIN(DATE_FORMAT(datecolumn,'%d')) from table)) 
FROM table t
group by DATE_FORMAT(t.datecolumn, '%Y-%m')
```

31,30,29 число подставится везде, не зависимо от количества дней в месяце

Comment: `SELECT min(DATE_FORMAT(`del_post`.`datecolumn`,'%Y/%m/%d')) FROM table `del_post`
group by DATE_FORMAT(`del_post`.`datecolumn` , '%Y-%m') ;
` такая ошибка : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table `del_post` group by DATE_FORMAT(`del_post`.`datecolumn` , '%Y-%m') LIMIT' at line 1

Comment: `FROM table del_post` в моем примере `table` - имя таблицы, `t` - алиас для быстрого обозначения, `t.datecolum` - название столбца с датой, я же правильно понимаю что у вас нет таблицы table?

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает